# Learning Java the "right way": any book that goes over DI, loosely coupling, writing testable code?

Tags: java

I'm comfing from the .net world, and want a book that goes over the 'right' way of coding.

Things like dependancy injection, loosely coupling of objects, how to layout your web application properly, unit-testing etc.

Comment: Webapp layout isn't really a Java concern. It's more a HTML/CSS concern.

Answer (score 3):

[Google code reviewer's guide](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/), a 38 page pdf which covers writing testable code, loose coupling and dependency injection. The [presentations](http://misko.hevery.com/presentations/) are also highly recommended.

[Dependency Injection](http://manning.com/prasanna/) covers the theory of why you would use dependency injection, in addition to the technical details.

Answer (score 2):

Three books that are language-agnostic, but are considered 'classics':

[Desing Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) (by GoF)

[Code complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556154844) (by Steve McConnell)

[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) (by Martin Fowler)

Important: don't read them like belles-lettres - read parts of them while practicing.

Comment: Do you know any for JAVA EE Basic to Advanced type of book?

Answer (score 2):

While it does not cover some of the things you mention, for me the book to learn Java the right way is definitely [Effective Java, Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).

[image: Effective Java, Second Edition]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/images/effective.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Bruce Eckel's [Thinking in Java](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4) is a very good introduction into Java for people who already know another language, the PDF version is free for download.

Answer (score 0):

Read a few books if you want, anything "agile", "spring", "TDD" will do, but to be real quick, get a job where they let you work together with a seasoned developer who does pair programming with you... and you will learn more quickly than you can even think about it...